# How to make AAC seekable over http stream using Android MediaPlayer?

Tags: android, stream, android-mediaplayer, aac

I have an app using MediaPlayer that works fine when I stream progressive download MP3s.  I have tried to use that same app to stream progress download AAC files.  And it plays the files fine.  What doesn't work is when I try to skip around in the stream using MediaPlayer.seekTo() with AAC.  This again works fine in mp3.  For the AAC stream it just restarts playing over at zero.

My feeling is that is encoding related.  That AAC file hasn't been configured correctly to stream.

Here is the output from MediaInfo tool:

```
Size: 2.3 MB
Format: QuickTime/MPEG-4/Motion JPEG 2000 format
Stream count: 2
Duration: 00:05:02
Bit rate: 64 kb/s
Meta info:
    album_artist: Red Hot Chili Peppers
    album: The Getaway
    minor_version: 512
    encoder: Lavf57.41.100
    title: Dark Necessities
    major_brand: M4V 
    track: 2
    disc: 1
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1
    artist: Red Hot Chili Peppers
    copyright: 2016 Warner Bros. Records Inc.
    genre: Alternative

Stream 0
Type: video
Codec: h264
Codec profile: High 10
FourCC: avc1
Duration: 00:00:00
Width: 350
Height: 350
Sample aspect ratio: 1:1
Display aspect ratio: 1:1
Pixel format: yuv420p10le
Frame rate: 90000 fps
Meta info:
    handler_name: VideoHandler
    language: und

Stream 1
Type: audio
Codec: aac
FourCC: mp4a
Duration: 00:05:02
Bit rate: 64 kb/s
Sample rate: 44100 Hz
Sample format: s16
Channel: 2
Meta info:
    handler_name: SoundHandler
    language: und
```

You'll notice it's really a video file with AAC audio and no real video included.  If that's the case then I figured it needs more metadata to know where to play when I ask for a portion of the stream that may or may not be loaded. Also videos need keyframes to know where to play from so I believe no keyframes or 'hint' boxes are included in the stream/file.

I haven't had any luck with finding any real details about what is missing or if this is possible or not.  I've tested this on other versions and it seems that prior to 5.0.2 it worked.  After 5.0.2 it does not work.  I haven't found any details about what changed in that version.

So this could either be a stream encoding issue that doesn't allow us to stream this file over a progressive download http(s) stream.  Or, it could be a bug in Android Media Player created sometime around 5.0.2 timeframe.  Or it could be both.

Why isn't this working?

Comment: Is there anyway to stream output as raw AAC (with ADTS header) instead of audio contained inside M4A / MP4? MP3 is working because you get MP3 frames (each is few millisecs of sound) so you just skip frames to seek. AAC is also frames (if you don't put inside container).  I'm not too familiar with Android SDK but I'm sure you can send bytes of frames to the SDK decoder. I'll investigate some options.

Comment: I was getting mixed messages on the support of ADTS in Android's player so I'm not exactly sure it works or not.  I look forward to hearing what you found out.

Comment: Have you got a sample stream link for checking?

Comment: It's copy written material so I don't feel like I should post it in a public forum.  I could provide access privately.

Comment: Open the file in a hex editor... Word search for the following strings : did it list 2 `traks`? one of those had `soun` nearby? After `soun` word does it list any `stco`, `stss`, `stsz` `stts` atoms (make sure it's all within `soun` area not within `vide` area)? If they exist it should be enough for an MPEG decoder so dunno... Also does your file extension end with `.mp4`, `.m4a` `.m4v` or `.aac`?

Comment: Send a small sample file to : valerio_charles@yahoo.com. I will check it for any visible issues...

Comment: @VC.One Thanks for your help.  I opened up the file and searched for soun, and I found those atoms in the file relatively close by.  I also had a chance to test it playing from a locally cached file, and it still didn't work.  However, if I play that file on VLC I can skip around so now I'm not so sure if this is a problem with the player or my code.

Answer (score 0):

Try with [Exoplayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer), it is so simple

[ExoPlayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer) has a number of advantages over Android’s built in MediaPlayer:

- Support for Dynamic Adaptive Streaming over HTTP (DASH) and SmoothStreaming, neither of which are are supported by MediaPlayer (it also supports HTTP Live Streaming (HLS), MP4, MP3, WebM, M4A, MPEG-TS and AAC).
- Support for advanced HLS features, such as correct handling of #EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY tags.
- The ability to customize and extend the player to suit your use case. [ExoPlayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer) is designed specifically with this in mind, and allows many components to be replaced with custom implementations.
- Easily update the player along with your application. Because [ExoPlayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer) is a library that you include in your application apk, you have control over which version you use and you can easily update to a newer version as part of a regular application update.

Comment: That was the other option, but I'm really interested in an answer about AAC streaming support in Android SDK.  I know I could rip out my existing code and try and replace it with something, but trading the devil you know for the devil you don't really isn't answering my question about streaming.

Comment: yes, it's optional & alternate solution for streaming. I'm sorry about your intention.